# How can I pass a variable onto a command's parameter in a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, variables, parameters, rsync

Example bash script demonstrating my problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

function exclude
{
    BACKUP_EXCLUDES="$BACKUP_EXCLUDES --exclude=\"$1\""
}

exclude "/proc"
exclude "/dev"
exclude "/mnt"
exclude "/media"
exclude "/lost+found"

echo $BACKUP_EXCLUDES
```

Output:

> --exclude="/proc" --exclude="/dev" --exclude="/mnt" --exclude="/media" --exclude="/lost+found"

Perfect!  But when I try adding:

```
rsync -ruvz $BACKUP_EXCLUDES / /some/backup/path
```

$BACKUP_EXCLUDES is completely ignored with no errors or warnings...  Why?

Comment: Exclude paths need to be relative, not absolute. You probably want the `-x` option instead of the excludes.

Comment: i would recommend:
--exclude-from=FILE

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use array:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

BACKUP_EXCLUDES=()
function exclude
{
  while
    (( $# ))
  do
    BACKUP_EXCLUDES+=(--exclude="$1")
    shift
  done
}
exclude /proc /dev /mnt /media
exclude "/lost+found"

rsync -ruvz "${BACKUP_EXCLUDES[@]}" / /some/backup/path
```

**the bash explanation:** please check @janos answer

**the zsh explanation (if it was Zsh):** when you used a string variable it was like you passed `--exclude="\"/proc\" --exclude=\"/media\" ..."` - so it was treated as long path with spaces - which never matched.

Comment: it looks like you're doing too much work with the while loop: `for arg; do BACKUP_EXCLUDES+=(--exclude="$arg"); done`

Comment: i did not used `for $arg` on purpose as in bigger scripts it would leave environment mess with `arg` variable and to prevent it you would need to `typeset arg` first - which in the end would be the same count of lines again

Comment: in bash (and the shebang implies this) it is *not* one long string argument. the zsh behavior is much better imho and prevents a lot of escaping errors, but it is not the cause of the problem here. more likely what janos said is the problem. your conclusion about arrays is correct, though, but please fix the argument about the cause.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because the quotes are included in the individual `--exclude` parameters. That is, `rsync` will ignore `"/proc"` instead of `/proc`. Of course `"/proc"` (with quotes) doesn't exist.

If you stick an eval in front of the command it will work, like this:

```
eval rsync -ruvz $BACKUP_EXCLUDES / /some/backup/path
```

In this case the `--exclude="/proc"` (and all others) will be evaluated to `--exclude=/proc`, that's why it will work.

But I think you should use arrays as proposed by @mpapis, or `--exclude-from=FILE` as proposed by a comment. Both are much better and cleaner solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and suggestion for arrays.  Unfortunately I cannot use -exclude-from as it's not compatible with duplicity, whereas --exclude seems to work with both rsync and duplicity.